# Cannot resolve myAPI. Is it an external library?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gradle

I am new to android programming language. I am referring to the [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints) , But failing to understand what MyAPI is in this piece of code. I found a similar question on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753730/cannot-resolve-symbol-myapi). However, I cannot even resolve this MyAPI library, and he could find it initially which later stopped working. Where can I find it?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Pair;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json.AndroidJsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClientRequestInitializer;

import java.io.IOException;

class SendRegisterInfo extends AsyncTask<Pair<Context, String>, Void, String> {
    private static MyApi myApiService = null;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Pair<Context, String>... params) {
        if(myApiService == null) {  // Only do this once
            MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                    // options for running against local devappserver
                    // - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
                    // - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
                    .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                        @Override
                        public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?>
                                                       abstractGoogleClientRequest)
                                throws IOException {
                            abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                        }
                    });
            // end options for devappserver

            myApiService = builder.build();
        }

        context = params[0].first;
        String name = params[0].second;

        try {
            return myApiService.sayHi(name).execute().getData();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely that documentation you link to shows you what MyAPI is, in the fourth screenshot?

Comment: But its failing to resolve for me. I have followed the exact steps. I guess, there should be some dependency that need to be added in the gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You can find MyApi.java in the backend.

[image: MyApi.java]

@Google Cloud Endpoints